# Why are the avatars' hair plaited in the grow tubes?

Tags: avatar

Simple question, why or how are the avatars' hair plaited in the grow tubes? Do the Na'vi grow hair that is plaited, or is it something else that just looks like hair?

[image]

Comment: I should imagine it's to keep it out of the way when the scientists need to inspect them. They're grown in the tubes but that doesn't mean that they're hermetically sealed inside them...

Comment: @Valorum, So they keep emptying those tubes to braid the avatars hair. Yep, I can believe that!!!

Comment: I'd guess that they empty them every few days/weeks/months to allow the scientists to perform tests on the avatar bodies like blood pressure analysis and Oxygen Sats.

Comment: @Valorum, then it should not be too hard to provide an answer!!! Looking forward to it.

Comment: Lots of discussion about this [here](https://forum.learnnavi.org/general-avatar-discussion/why-the-navi-have-long-hair/40/).

Comment: @Longshanks, interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The hair has evidently been plaited by the science staff, presumably in the same manner that a Na'vi would have their hair plaited from an early age by their caregivers (and then learn to do it themselves) in order to protect their hyper-sensitive '*queue*'.

> At first glance, a human might think of the Na'vi queue as simply a
> long, rather ostentatious hair braid. **This seemingly conventional
> braid actually sheathes a “neural whip” that is an extension of the
> Na’vi’s nervous system.** At its distal end is a remarkably intricate
> branching of neural tendrils that can be connected to similar
> structures of other life forms, both animal and plant. This connection
> allows a Na'vi to exchange sensory information with other creatures,
> and members of the zooplantae phylum, the animal-like plants which are
> unique to Pandora. **From birth on, the Na’vi individual’s hair is
> painstakingly braided over the antenna-like neural whip, protecting it
> from harm.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Pandorapedia: The Na'vi Queue](https://www.pandorapedia.com/navi/appearance_behavior/navi_queue.html)</sup></sub>

One assumes that if they don't do this, the avatar would potentially suffer harm to their queue from moving around in the tube and periodic draining.